# python 3 with json dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, file, dictionary

I'm currently working on a project, and I have saved dictionaries list into a JSON file, separated by lines.

How can I convert the JSON dictionaries back into the PYTHON program, putting it back to the original variable name?

Let's say I have a dictionary list like this:

```
a = { "a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
b = {"alpha":1, "bravo": 2, "charlie":3}
```

I have converted it into JSON file by doing this:

```
with open('example.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(a, outfile)
    outfile.write('\n')
    json.dump(b, outfile)
```

And when I open the program again, I want it saved by loading the JSON files, separating each JSON-dictionary into each Python-dictionary.
Any help would be grateful.

Comment: PLEASE DON'T YELL

Comment: Why don't you put them in a list so they're saving as a JSON array?

Comment: How do I do so? I'm kinda new to Python and JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the dictionaries will be on separate lines, you just need to read the lines and use the `json` module to parse each line into a dictionary. Something like this:

```
with open("example.txt", "r") as infile:
    lines = infile.read().splitlines()
    a = json.loads(lines[0])
    b = json.loads(lines[1])
```

Using `infile.read().splitlines()` will remove the unwanted `\n` between the two JSONs.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of your `with` block is incorrect. all of the code referencing the `outfile` variable should be indented inside that block, otherwise the file resource is closed when the code down below is executed.